# How to construct an integer with spaces between numbers?

Tags: python, initialization, int

In Java, I think you can initialize int `40000000` as `40_000_000`.

Is there anything like that in python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Python 3.6, the same syntax is accepted in Python: [What's New in 3.6: Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-515-underscores-in-numeric-literals)

Comment: Does it have a name, that kind of intializing numbers underscore ? And can you link documentation where can I find more about it ? Thank you.